# CASE WHEN with LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, symfony, dql

I want to select the left join table depending on a value from other table.
So I tried this, but not working:

```
CASE WHEN c.catId LIKE "%s%" THEN 
  LEFT JOIN AppBundle:newspaper_subcategories cat WITH c.catIdShort = cat.id
ELSE 
  LEFT JOIN AppBundle:newspaper_categories cat WITH c.catIdShort = cat.id
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply left join the two tables but use the CASE statement on the column clauses

```
SELECT 
  . . . 
 CASE WHEN c.catId LIKE '%s%' 
 THEN sub.somecolumn
 ELSE cat.somecolumn
 END
  . . . 
LEFT JOIN AppBundle:newspaper_subcategories sub ON c.catIdShort = cat.id
LEFT JOIN AppBundle:newspaper_categories cat ON c.catIdShort = cat.id
```